# CentOS 8 system-config-users

Tags: centos, users

I would like to install `system-config-users` on CentOS but I can't. I get an error: "No match found". Can anyone help me? Is there any similar software for CentOS 8?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren’t using the command line tools (useradd, usermod, groupadd, etc) then the tool you should use is the web console [Cockpit](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/getting-started-with-system-administration_configuring-basic-system-settings#adding-new-accounts-in-the-web-console_managing-user-accounts). That’s what RHEL uses to replace tools like system-config-* tools in previous releases.

Comment: Unfortunately, Cockpit doesn't support editing groups.